# Laravel 5.3: PHP Version issue on remote host

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.3

I am using Site5 which [allows](http://kb.site5.com/php/how-to-change-your-php-version/) multiple php. So I tried to run `composer install` and it welcomed me with various version related errors. Laravel 5.3 needs 5.6+ and I have 5.5 installed but my hosting allows various version including PHP7. PHP7 is installed as `/usr/local/php70/bin/php`

Now how can I make `composer` and `artisan` to use these commands. Specially composer

Comment: PHP 7 will need to be on your PATH/bin. From memory site5 allows multiple PHP versions but enables them through your applications' .htaccess file by enabling the specific PHP version module, but obviously that won't work for CLI. You will probably need to ask their support to point PATH at the 7 install bin.

Comment: `/usr/local/php70/bin/php composer.phar install`

Comment: @AlexBlex It worked, please make it an Answer so I accept